# Disable WPF Button Hover Effect

Tags: c#, wpf

The standard WPF Button control has a mouseover highlight that changes the colour of the control. I'm trying to disable this effect. Whilst I see lots of questions and answers to this on SO that involve changes to XAML, I'm trying to do this 100% programmatically, and I haven't been able to find any solution to this problem.

I don't have any XAML, as my WPF app dynamically adds a list of (derived) button controls to the form. The derived button class has no XAML whatsoever.

```cs
var button = new CustomButton(); // Inherits System.Windows.Controls.Button
button.Content = textBlock;  // System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
// other various property changes to the custom button removed
button.Focusable = false;
grid.Children.Add(button);
```

The button works perfectly with my custom code, but I just can't remove the mouseover effect. This is particularly bad, as it's being used on a touch screen, so the last touched button retains the mouseover effect until another button is pressed or the user clicks an unused area of the window.

Thanks to Kostas in the comments, I now know I need to create a global style and apply this to my custom control, however as per my original question, all the examples of doing this involve XAML, so my question really ought to be more specifically, how can I create a global style without a mouse over trigger, entirely programmatically?

Comment: Create a global style for your custom button and remove the mouse over trigger?

Comment: Thanks @KostasK. I have no idea where to start with that (new to WPF), but I'll go do some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of the puzzle I was missing, was that the XAML for the style doesn't need to go in the button class, it instead goes into the parent window XAML. The Style is then added to the button class as it's added to the Window:

```
<Window x:Class="SomeOrg.SomeApp.WpfInterface.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfInterface"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SomeApp" Height="450" Width="800"
        Background="#ffffffe1">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Width="Auto" Background="#ffffffe1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the parent window's code, where the custom button is added to the window, the above style (MyButton), is applied as follows:

```
var button = new CustomButton();
customButton.Style = (Style) this.Resources["MyButton"];
grid.Children.Add(button);
```